# bootstrap 3.3.6 dropdown not working, DataTables makes it worse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying to use bootstrap dropdown buttons together with data tables.

I have 2 issues.
1) the new style of dropdowns doesn't work properly.
2) including data tables stops both new & old style dropdowns working

here's the html.

I've repro'd this problem on Safari 9.0.3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datatables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                New Style
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Old Style
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-2.2.0/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datatables.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Snippet of web page:
/// I don't have enough reputation to post 3 links, so in lieu of a picture, here are not quite 1k words. Two normal looking BS buttons, one grey (new style) no caret, above other blue/green (old style) with a caret.///

Note that the new style button does not have a caret.

Clicking on either of these does not result in a drop down menu being shown.

After commenting out the `<script>` element that includes datatables I get this for the New Style markup - not great, but at least there's a menu of sorts:

[New Style popup with datatables commented out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhwWB.png)

Whereas the old style of markup works just fine:

[Old style popup with datatables commented out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQNCb.png)

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Some checks I've already anticipated:

- does my bootstrap disti include the dropdown module? Yes.
- does the order in which scripts are included affect the outcome? No.
- does commenting out the data table css link have any effect? No.

I'd appreciate any and all help on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

Attach an event listener to the button and toggle the dropdown's state when it's clicked. $delete is a shortcut to one of the button's ancestor's in the DOM.

```
$delete.find('.dropdown-toggle').on ('click', function (ev) {
    console.log ('delete dropdown clicked');
    $(this).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

This works on both old & new style dropdowns, but the new style still has the formatting issues identified in the original post.

[RTFM citation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-1)

Answer (score 0):

Schoolboy error, I'm afraid.

I discovered I was including jQuery & bootstrap twice - once explicitly via   tags in index.hmtl, and once implicitly because datatables.min.js (helpfully?) adds jQuery and Bootstrap to itself.

Things behave as they should with just the one include for these scripts.